# Stop VMWare moving the mouse cursor to the center

Tags: vmware-player

I'm using a dual-monitor setup and in one of the monitors I have a maximized VMWare virtual machine. Everytime the virtual machine's window receives focus it moves the mouse to the center of that monitor. If the virtual machine window is not maximized the mouse doesn't jump.

Some situations where the mouse is moved:

- A program in the guest OS has focus, and I minimize that window. VMWare gains focus and moves the mouse away.
- A program in the guest OS has focus, I click on VMWare's toolbar (in the middle of the top edge) to access any of its menus or buttons (like minimize, restore, File menu, etc.) and the mouse jumps to the center of the screen.

Is there a way to configure VMWare to stop doing that? I've looked in all the configuration and setting windows and haven't been able to find anything that helps me.

My host is Windows 7, and I'm using VMWare Player version 4.0.4 build-744019 to use Ubuntu 10.04 as a guest. I have VMware tools installed in the guest, version 8.8.4 build-743747 (according to `vmware-toolbox`)

Comment: Do you have VMWare tools installed on the guest virtual machine?

Comment: @David I do have them installed

Comment: I have this exact same issue. None of the mouse settings (optimize for games, etc) did anything to correct this issue.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem make ScrollLock is off.

Comment: I had the same problem as described and THIS was the solution for me..

Comment: Weird solution but it worked for me as well. I can't find any resource about this online, so surely it's a bug in VMware?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had exactly same problem. I reinstalled VMware tools and it helped. Now I have version 9.6.5.2700074.

To reinstall VMware tools: When Virtual Machine is working go to Player menu -> Manage -> Reinstall VMware Tools.